# Python - Hexadecimal to Decimal conversions

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x

I have written a python 2 program for a school project to convert from hexadecimal to decimal without using built-in functions and vice versa in python. I would like to know how I can make my code more concise - specifically, the "d_func" function.

```
d_dict = {"0" : 0, "1" : 1, "2" : 2, "3" : 3, "4" : 4, "5" : 5, "6" : 6, "7" : 7, "8" : 8, "9" : 9, "A" : 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13, "E" : 14, "F": 15}

def d_func(digit, mode):
    if mode == 1:
        for x in range(len(d_dict.keys())):
            if digit == list(d_dict.keys())[x]:
                return x
    else:
        for y in range(len(d_dict.values())):
            if digit == list(d_dict.values())[y]:
                return list(d_dict.keys())[y]

def hd_func(h_num):
    d_num, p = 0, 0

    for digit in range(len(h_num), 0, -1):
        d_num = d_num + 16 ** p * d_func(h_num[digit - 1], 1)
        p += 1

    return str(d_num)

def dh_func(d_num):
    f_list, h_num, p = [], "", 0

    while d_num > 0:
        f_list.append(d_num % 16)
        d_num //= 16 

    for f in f_list[::-1]:
        h_num += d_func(f, 2)

    return h_num

func_dict = {"h": hd_func, "d": dh_func}
u_choice, u_num = input("Enter [H] for Hexadecimal to Decimal, [D] for Decimal to Hexadecimal"), input("Enter the number: ")
print(func_dict[u_choice.lower()](u_num))
```

Comment: Please use `python-3.x` in the future, as `python-2.x` has reached it's [end of life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Comment: I use python 3 outside of school but my school uses an online version of python 2, so I am required to write and submit programs in python 2.

Comment: As long as you know to use `python-3.x`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First -- document your code!  I read through your `d_func` function and here's my attempt at writing a docstring for what it does, with Python-2-compatible type hints.  Hopefully I got it right.  :)

```
def d_func(digit, mode):
    # type: (Union[str, int], int) -> Union[int, str, None]
    """Mode 1: give the int value of the hex digit.
    Other modes: give the hex digit of the given value.
    Returns None if you give it a bad value, I guess?
    """
    if mode == 1:
        for x in range(len(d_dict.keys())):
            if digit == list(d_dict.keys())[x]:
                return x
    else:
        for y in range(len(d_dict.values())):
            if digit == list(d_dict.values())[y]:
                return list(d_dict.keys())[y]
    return None  # stumblebum
```

Right off the bat: this should not be one function.  (The fact that it can return either an `int` or a `str` depending on its input type is a good clue!)  You should have one function that converts value to digit and another that converts digit to value; there's no value at all to having one function that does completely different things depending on a flag you pass it.

Second: yes, this can be a lot simpler.  I think you could implement d_func as follows:

```
d_dict = {"0" : 0, "1" : 1, "2" : 2, "3" : 3, "4" : 4, "5" : 5, "6" : 6, "7" : 7, "8" : 8, "9" : 9, "A" : 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13, "E" : 14, "F": 15}
d_dict_reverse = {v: d for d, v in d_dict.iteritems()}  # this is just building a new dictionary with the keys and values swapped

def d_func(digit, mode):
    # type: (Union[str, int], int) -> Union[int, str]
    if mode == 1:
        return d_dict[digit]
    else:
        return d_dict_reverse[digit]
```

At that point, it doesn't need to be a function at all, because you're just doing a simple dictionary lookup.  Give your dictionaries reasonable names that say what they do:

```
digit_to_value = {
    "0" : 0, "1" : 1, "2" : 2, "3" : 3, "4" : 4, "5" : 5, "6" : 6, "7" : 7, 
    "8" : 8, "9" : 9, "A" : 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13, "E" : 14, "F": 15
}
value_to_digit = {v: d for d, v in digit_to_value.iteritems()}
```

and then instead of:

```
d_num = d_num + 16 ** p * d_func(h_num[digit - 1], 1)
```

do:

```
d_num = d_num + 16 ** p * digit_to_value[h_num[digit - 1]]
```

and instead of:

```
    for f in f_list[::-1]:
        h_num += d_func(f, 2)
```

do:

```
    for f in f_list[::-1]:
        h_num += value_to_digit[f]
```

With this approach, not only do you not have to write a function, but unlike your function the dictionary will automatically raise a `KeyError` if you provide the wrong kind of input, e.g. if you do `value_to_digit[100]` or `digit_to_value[1]`.  Raising an error ASAP when you mess up (aka "fail fast") is good, because it makes it easier to figure out exactly where your bug is.  :)

Comment: `d_func` could be written in one line: `return d_dict[digit] if mode else d_dict_reverse[digit]`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Sam I want to point out some other things

## Avoid typing long list/dict constants

Very often you can construct them by code, which is less error prone. Instead of

```
d_dict = {"0" : 0, "1" : 1, "2" : 2, "3" : 3, "4" : 4, "5" : 5, "6" : 6, "7" : 7, "8" : 8, "9" : 9, "A" : 10, "B" : 11, "C" : 12, "D" : 13, "E" : 14, "F": 15}
```

you do

```
import string

digit = dict(zip(range(16), string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase))
value = {v: k for k, v in digit.items()}
```

If you type all the values you have to write test cases for all of them.

## Loop like a pro

You prefer to loop like

```
for i in range(len(something)):
    print(something[i])
```

That is not how it is done in Python as it is error prone. In Python you loop like

```
for e in something:
    print(e)
```

If for some reason you really also need the index you use `enumerate()`

```
for i, e in enumerate(something):
    print(i, e)
```

That said we change

```
def hd_func(h_num):
    d_num, p = 0, 0

    for digit in range(len(h_num), 0, -1):
        d_num = d_num + 16 ** p * d_func(h_num[digit - 1], 1)
        p += 1

    return str(d_num)
```

to

```
def to_int(s):
     i = 0
     for c in s:
         i = i*16 + value[c]
     return i
```

The loop is much cleaner. By changing the algorithm I also got rid of the counter. Also I think returning a string is wrong here and I changed that to an `int`. Also I changed the function name to fit the return type and be less cryptic.

## Do not initialize as a tuple if it isn't one

```
f_list, h_num, p = [], "", 0
```

These variables do not form a natural tuple. Use three lines of code. Readability counts. Of course there is nothing wrong with initializing e. g. coordinates in a single line.

## Do initialize variables right before you need them

In the line

```
f_list, h_num, p = [], "", 0
```

the variable `h_num` is initialized at the beginning of the function while it is needed just before the second loop. Compare the readability of

```
def dh_func(d_num):
    f_list, h_num, p = [], "", 0

    while d_num > 0:
        f_list.append(d_num % 16)
        d_num //= 16 

    for f in f_list[::-1]:
        h_num += d_func(f, 2)

    return h_num
```

to

```
def dh_func(d_num):

    f_list = []
    while d_num > 0:
        f_list.append(d_num % 16)
        d_num //= 16 

    h_num = ""
    for f in f_list[::-1]:
        h_num += d_func(f, 2)

    return h_num
```

## Avoid adding strings

In the second loop of function `dh_func` (see above) you use `+` for appending to a string. This is a inefficient operation in python. There is the string method `join()` for that task. So we rewrite the function with a better function name to

```
def to_hex(n):
    l = []
    while n > 0:
        l.append(digit[n%16])
        n //= 16
    return "".join(l[::-1])
```